# Macbook Air mid 2013 not charging

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a macbook air mid 2013 model. It worked with no problem till now. Today when I opened the macbook it shows no charge symbol(I mean when you press power button it shows a battery icon in a black screen like iPhone does when its battery is drained).

I connected the charger but there is no led light(green or amber). It is not detecting the charger . I checked the same charger in another macbook.The charger works perfectly.

I tried doing SMC and PRAM reset. Since there is no power in the machine nothing happens. Please help.

The OS is Mavericks.

I got the macbook in London and I am in India now. Will the Apple warranty work internationally?.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I gave it to the Apple authorised repair centre. They told me IO chip and wire had to be replaced. Since it was in warranty it got it repaired for free.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out!  For anyone checking, yes, AppleCare does work internationally.  I think the biggest challenge is usually finding a service location but AppleCare should be able to direct you to one.